# ASP.NET mvc css and js linking issue with ssl

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, ssl-certificate

I just enabled ssl in visual studio 2012. and trying to load site with `https://localhost:44300/` instead of `http://localhost:51360/`. But all css and js is not woring. While with `http://localhost:51360/` it works properly. I'm testing ssl to local machine before uploading to lice server.

This is how I'm linking css in layout file.

```
link href="~/r/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
link href="~/r/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<br>
link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href="~/r/images/favicon.png" />
```

I have tried with

```
href="https://localhost:44300/r/css/style.css"
<br>    
href="https://localhost:44300/r/css/bootstrap.css"
<br>
href="https://localhost:44300/r/images/favicon.png"
```

but still same issue, pages load but css and js not applying on them.

Looking for help!!!

Comment: What is not working specifically? Do you get any errors in your browser console? This is pretty much the browser blocking you from loading your external resources because you are loading them via http. Try inspecting the console (f12) and post the erros here.

Comment: I also forget, you could be running into not valid SSL certificate. Since you are running local your certificate is probably not trusted by an certified authority. If that's the problem either get a valid SSL certificate, or add the one you have opening MMC in windows.

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (OK)

Comment: I tried with live server as well using valid ssl certificate, but same problem. actually it give no error on web page. it don't apply styling, and javascript as every time, try to retrieve resources, it got 404 error.

Comment: The 404 is when SSL is enabled? if you open your site in Google Chrome or Firefox, open the developers tools menu F12. All the scripts that weren't loaded should be there with errors. 404 tells you it couldn't find your scripts.

Comment: solved it out, by removing the .js and .css from bundle names in bundle file.